# IE8 spacing issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, spacing

I have a button style that ie8 is adding extra space to, I think it has something to do with the min-height but can't figure our what, I've tried overflow hidden and min-height hacks but nothing changes,

js fiddle link - [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/m3QXx/)

below is the code (thanks whoever formatted it):

```css
.button {
  float:left;
  width:auto;
  min-width:80px;
  min-height:40px;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 0;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:20px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#e4e5e6;
  background-color:#d04c21;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-left:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:all .2s ease-out;
  -o-transition:all .2s ease-out;
  transition:all .2s ease-out;
}

.switch .button-group .button {
  min-height:30px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  color:#393c3e;
  background-color:#b1b2b3;
  -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:all .2s ease-out;
  -o-transition:all .2s ease-out;
  transition:all .2s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code more nicely, and create a demo over on http://codepen.io or http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I've added a jsFiddle link above.

Answer (score 0):

`-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;` 
ie8 has partial support for box-sizing. Also `min-width:80px;` will interpret it as: http://caniuse.com/#search=min-width

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/m3QXx/2/

I changed:

```
.switch .button-group{padding: 0 0 0 5px; }

.button {height: 100%;}
```